# Data from presure sensor to home widget

Tags: android

Im starting to develop my first home screen widget. I got activity where i can read and display data from presure sensore by:

```
public class BaroWidgetActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
[...]
   public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float millibars_of_pressure = event.values[0];
      }
}
```

I also have home widget with simple textview. And i want to display current preseure there every 30min. But i dont know how to do it, so some service will not constant work and not drain battery. I dont want to display all presure change but read current presure every 30 min. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Look into Android services

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html